# Invalid macro expansion argument character

Tags: ios, make, gcc, arm

I am attempting to compile [pooler-cpuminer](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer) and when running make I get this error:

```
sha2-arm.S:190:invalid macro expansion argument character (+)
```

Any help? I've looked and haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aha I fixed it. There was a nomacro.pl script I had to run.